# if Checkbox1 is checked enable Checkbox1 like same in squence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to make a filter if checkbox1 is checked of column 1 then the checkbox1 of column 2 should be enabled and vice versa, here it will make you more clear with my experiment, 
**and also my issue is if i uncheck any checkbox from column 1 all the checkbox from column2 gets unselected instead of viceversa**

**Html**

```
<ul>
<h1>Column1</h1>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="filter" checked /> filter1</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="filter" checked /> filter2</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="filter" checked /> filter3</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="filter" checked /> filter4</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="filter" checked /> filter5</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="filter" checked /> filter6</li>
</ul>
<form action="#" method="post">
<ul>
<h1>Column2</h1>
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked /> checkbox1</li>
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked /> checkbox2</li>
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked /> checkbox3</li>
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked /> checkbox4</li>
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked /> checkbox5</li>
<li><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked /> checkbox6</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.filter').click(function () {
    //check if checkbox is checked
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        $('.checkbox').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable input

    } else {
        $('.checkbox').attr('disabled', true); //disable input
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tuttu88/mdwqvsvr/1/

Comment: If the checkboxes in column one and column two must always be in the same state, why do they both exist (and pretend to be independent)? Also, your HTML is invalid: a `<h1>` element cannot be nested within an `<ul>`, it first has to be wrapped in a `<li>` element.

Comment: column2 will be a hidden part in a form section which can be placed any where in page, so if i click a filter from another section it should work

Comment: Your headings can't be children of `<ul>` elements.

Comment: @j08691 i am not getting you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use index of parent of clicked checkbox along with eq selector to target the desired checkbox in other list:

```
$('.filter').click(function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('.checkbox').eq($(this).parent().index()-1).removeAttr('disabled'); //enable input
 } else {
     $('.checkbox').eq($(this).parent().index()-1).attr('disabled', true); //disable input
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p0sdudg5/)**